# Are people lazy because they are destined to be lazy?

Tags: tafseer, behavior, qadar

I recently came across the following Hadith and I am curious about the implications of it:

> Ali narrated that one day the Messenger of Allah was sitting with a
>   wooden stick in his hand with which he was scratching the ground. He
>   raised his head and said, “There is none of you, but has his place
>   assigned either in the Fire or in Paradise.” They (the Companions)
>   inquired, “O Allah’s Messenger! Why should we carry on doing good
>   deeds, shall we depend (upon Qadar) and give up work?” Muhammad said:
>   “**No, carry on doing good deeds, for everyone will find it easy (to do)
>   such deeds that will lead him towards that for which he has been
>   created.**” Then he recited the verse: “As for him who gives (in
>   charity) and keeps his duty to Allah and fears Him, and believes in
>   al-Husna, We will make smooth for him the path of Ease (goodness)
>   (Surah al-Lail 92:5-7). Sahih Muslim

Some people are hard-working while others are lazy. 
**In the context of this Hadith, can it be said that certain people are destined to succeed while others are meant to fail?**

Comment: Read 1 rukoo of the Quran?

Comment: @Casanova I meant one section.

Comment: You mean one juz or chapter of the 30 chapters of the Qu'ran or just a random bit of verses?

Comment: @Armaan I am not entirely sure but I think it is called a "hizb-quarter". Allah knows best.

Comment: Are there 30 of them?

Comment: @Armaan No. There aren't 30 of them. You are referring to `Ajza (singular: Juz)`. There are sections within each `Juz`. There are further divisions in those sections. I am referring to those divisions.

Answer (score 1):

Some people are lazy. whether it's by their nature and they did not change it , or if they just like becoming so.

They have choice.

According to the hadith , it is affirming that Allah knows the destiny of all people.

so , wheteher they will be "lazy" , or will be lazy at first but will change themselves later , or not lazy at first but became lazy , or not lazy at all .. etc. It is all previously known by God .

Does it mean that a person should be lazy or do nothing , since everything is known previously ? **"No, carry on doing good deeds"** or as the prophet said peace and blessings be upon him .

check here https://islamqa.info/en/49039:

"*Ruling on citing al-qadar (divine will and decree) as an excuse for committing sin or failing to do obligatory dutie*s: "